# How to set multiple pushpins from code-behind (WP8)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to add a multiple pushpins to map.

Here's the XAML:

```
<maps:Map ZoomLevel="8" Height="500" x:Name="map1" Width="415" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children>
                    <toolkit1:MapItemsControl x:Name="PushpinCollection">
                        <toolkit1:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <toolkit1:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coords}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit1:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </toolkit1:MapItemsControl>
                </toolkit1:MapExtensions.Children>
            </maps:Map>
```

Here's the code:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
        var sigCol = new SignalCollection(xmlDataSource);
        var allSignals = await sigCol.GetData(false, false, "UA");
        ObservableCollection<IssueDescription> signalsWithCoords = new ObservableCollection<IssueDescription>();
        foreach (var signal in allSignals)
        {
            if (signal.Coords != null)
            {
                signalsWithCoords.Add(signal);                    
            }
        }
        PushpinCollection.ItemsSource = signalsWithCoords;
    }
```

But the last string throws NullReferenceException. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and see where exacly the exception is thrown and what is the content of your variables?

Comment: @Romasz, Can you tell me what I should to do to find where exacly exception is thrown?
Btw, signalsWithCoords variable is not null, it contains 193 elements.

Comment: I found that PushpinCollection is null, it throws exception. But why this happens? PushpinCollection is a x:Name of MapItemsControl in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've checked `PushpinCollection` exists (is not null) and the following code should work:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
    var sigCol = new SignalCollection(xmlDataSource);
    var allSignals = await sigCol.GetData(false, false, "UA");
    ObservableCollection<IssueDescription> signalsWithCoords = new ObservableCollection<IssueDescription>();
    foreach (var signal in allSignals)
    {
        if (signal.Coords != null)
        {
            signalsWithCoords.Add(signal);                    
        }
    }
    MapItemsControl PushpinCol = MapExtensions.GetChildren(map1).FirstOrDefault(x => x is MapItemsControl) as MapItemsControl;

    PushpinCol.ItemsSource = signalsWithCoords;
}
```

---

Digging a little further it turns out that this seems to be a little bug. In the source code `DependencyProperty NameProperty` is registered as `"ItemTemplate"` - which probably prevents from getting it by name from code.

**EDIT** - after comments

Digging a little more in the source code brigns an information that this exception is thrown by MapExtension when `Items.Count > 0` and you try to change ItemsSource. Here is an approach which allows you to change ItemsSource:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var xmlDataSource = new XmlDataSource();
    var sigCol = new SignalCollection(xmlDataSource);
    var allSignals = await sigCol.GetData(false, false, "UA");
    ObservableCollection<IssueDescription> signalsWithCoords = new ObservableCollection<IssueDescription>();
    foreach (var signal in allSignals)
    {
        if (signal.Coords != null)
        {
            signalsWithCoords.Add(signal);                    
        }
    }
    MapItemsControl PushpinCol = MapExtensions.GetChildren(map1).FirstOrDefault(x => x is MapItemsControl) as MapItemsControl;
    if (PushpinCol != null && PushpinCol.ItemsSource != null)
    {
        (PushpinCol.ItemsSource as IList).Clear();
        PushpinCol.ItemsSource = null;
    }
    PushpinCol.ItemsSource = signalsWithCoords;
}
```

On the other hand consider making your Collection static and set it as ItemsSource once.

Comment: Btw, how to extract an object that was binded with pushpin? I use MouseLeftButtonUp event, but I can't convert a sender object to IssueDescription.

Comment: @splash27 Have you tried: ((sender as Pushpin).DataContext as IssueDescription)?

Comment: There is one more error. When I try to reload page, It crashes at the last line with exception InvalidOperation: Items must be empty before use ItemsSource. I can't use Items.Clear() method, because Items is non writable property. Is there the way to fix it?

Comment: @splash27 There are few answer if you search for that exception - they should probably help. Is it needed that you create ObservableCollection each time you Navigate to your page? Set ItemsSource only if its null?

Comment: I get exception if I return to this page using back button. signalsWithCoors collection may be another that time and I need to set this refreshed signalsWithCoords collection as ItemsSource, but I can't, because PushpinCol already has Items, that was cached when I visited this page first time.

Comment: @splash27 I've dug a little more and added an approach in my answer that should work. Good luck.